# I've created a request method, but the admin needs to login first before acquiring the token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, axios, react-router-dom

I've created a request method so I can easily fetch it, but when I first run it, I recevied this message.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

I know where I get this, it's because my program automatically calls it when I start it automatically.

So what I want is to stop running these codes as long as I'm not logged in.

login.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { useHistory } from "react-router"
import { login } from "../../redux/apiCalls"

const Login = () => {
    let history = useHistory()
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const handleClick = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        login(dispatch,{username,password})
        history.push('/home')
        
    }

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center", height: '100vh', flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <form action="">
            <input style={{padding: 10, marginBottom:20}} value={username}  type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input style={{padding: 10, marginBottom:20}} value={password} type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <button style={{padding: 10, width: 100}} onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

requestMethod.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api'
const TOKEN =
  JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root')).user).currentUser
    .accessToken || null

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
})

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
})
```

app.js

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrivateRoute from '../src/components/PrivateRoute'
import './App.css'
// import Sidebar from './components/sidemenu/Sidebar'
import Home from './pages/home/Home'
import Login from './pages/login/Login'
function App() {
  const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin)

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" auth={admin} component={Home}></PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>

  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: How you set token `localStorage.setItem('persist:root')`?

Comment: I empty the token first in the requestMethod.js because it gave me an error already. after emptying it. I login it, and then I put it again. That is why I'm thinking of how can I stop the requestMethod and let allow the user to login before running. (if applicable)
@VitaliyRayets